# Other way to validate a input with html5 regex, with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

i need to check a html input with a regex pattern with vanilla javaScript, but it's a little bit tricky, i go back to the parent to validate the input,  it works but it's not beautiful as expected.

Js:

```
input.parentNode.querySelector(':valid')
```

Html:

```
<input type="tel" id="fos_user_registration_form_mobileNumber" name="fos_user_registration_form[mobileNumber]" required="required" pattern="^0[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|9]\d{8}$" maxlength="10">
```

Is it possible to do otherwise ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to go back to the parent? The `input` cannot have any children, thus hopping to the parent from the input seems wrong if you need validity of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`validity` property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-cva-validity):

> The validity attribute's getter must return a `ValidityState` object that represents the [validity states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#validity-states) of this element. This object is live.

...where one of the states is a boolean `valid` flag:

```
if (input.validity.valid) {
    // yes
} else {
    // no
}
```

Or [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```
if (input.matches(":valid")) {
    // yes
} else {
    // no
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's very usefull